# thesaurus.com says that a synonym of RESIST is ABIDE. Can you provide an example?

Tags: ambiguity

The best I can come up with is that the opposite of resist is to accept, and "abiding" is something shy of accepting, so if abiding is not accepting, and resisting is not accepting, then abiding and resisting are the same.

But can you explain how the words are synonyms?

[image]

Comment: Due to a lack of sources, this is not going to be an answer. Thinking of "abide", one would think that the meaning is to accept. But, "abiding" could also be done without accepting, as in the case of abiding by a law for the sake of maintaining status quo, regardless of acceptance or belief. In a way, that could be a withstanding.

Comment: Why the downvote with no net about the downvote?

Answer (score 4):

A possible meaning of "abide" is "withstand", hence making it a synonym of "resist".

Sources:

- Oxford English Dictionary -  **5.** *trans.* To await defiantly; to encounter, withstand, or sustain; to face, esp. in combat. Now somewhat *arch.*
- Merriam-Webster - **1 b** :  to endure without yielding :  withstand 
  ( https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abide )

I'd agree with the OED that this usage is somewhat archaic.

The example in M-W is "*abide the onrush of the enemy*".

The examples in the OED include:

- 1932   R. Kipling *Storm Cone*   It is decreed that we abide / The weight of gale against the tide.
- 1963   T. A. Dodge *Caesar I. ix. 129*   Calling a council of war, it was determined to hold the camp and abide the attack which the barbarians were sure to make.